# I'm trying install maven in eclipse. But I cannot make maven-archetype

Tags: eclipse, maven

Specs :
Windows 10
JDK: 1.6
Maven version: 3.2.1
Eclipse: Kepler

I confirmed `mvn -version` and `java -version` at CMD.
And in eclipse I clicked Window>preferences>maven>User Setting and Installation for set the settings.xml.

I can't search how to fix maven web creation denied. I put two photos about my circumstance.

[image: the version is released]

[image: error comments]

Comment: Other than Windows 10, every version you're using is massively out of date. Use the current releases instead.

Comment: Eclipse Kepler is 8 years and 18 releases old, not many people are going to remember what to do on such an old release.

Comment: Also Maven version 3.2.1 is really old... use most recent version 3.8.2...